# How do I flush the buffered data in a DeflatorOutputStream

Tags: java, flush, deflate

I would like to be able to flush any pending data in a DeflaterOutputStream and read it in a InflaterInputStream.  However, it appears that flush(), doesn't do this.  Is there another way?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos);

for(char ch = 'a';ch <= 'z';ch ++) {
    dos.write(ch);
    dos.flush();
    System.out.println("compressed size = "+baos.toByteArray().length);
}
dos.close();
System.out.println("After close, compressed size = "+baos.toByteArray().length);
```

What I expect to see is the  size increasing on each flush as it flushes any pending/buffered data. However, it doesn't. It just stays in a buffer until I close the stream.

```
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
compressed size = 2
After close, compressed size = 34
```

If DeflaterOutputStream doesn't support this, is there a compressed stream which does?

I have looked at Apache Commons Compress and the only stream which flushes the data is XZCompressorInputStream but in doing so, the data is about 50% larger than not compressing.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XZCompressorOutputStream dos = new XZCompressorOutputStream(baos);

for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    dos.write(("Hello world").getBytes());
    baos2.write(("Hello world").getBytes());
    dos.flush();
    System.out.println("compressed size = " + baos.toByteArray().length);
}
dos.close();
System.out.println("After close, compressed size = " + baos.toByteArray().length);
System.out.println("uncompressed size = " + baos2.toByteArray().length);
```

finally prints

```
compressed size = 388
After close, compressed size = 424
uncompressed size = 286
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have read the Javadoc. There is an option to the constructor `syncFlush` and if true gives the behaviour I want.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DeflaterOutputStream dos = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos, true);

for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
    dos.write(("Hello world").getBytes());
    baos2.write(("Hello world").getBytes());
    dos.flush();
    System.out.println("compressed size = " + baos.toByteArray().length);
}
dos.close();
System.out.println("After close, compressed size = " + baos.toByteArray().length);
System.out.println("uncompressed size = " + baos2.toByteArray().length);
```

prints finally

```
compressed size = 212
compressed size = 220
After close, compressed size = 226
uncompressed size = 286
```

Note: this was only added in Java 7, and I was looking at Java 6.

Comment: Running into the same problem. Damn Java 6 compatibility!